# Which events can I observe with Shiny observeEvent?

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shiny-reactivity

observeEvent requires eventExpr. This is demonstrated simply in the examples with input$button etc.

However, with for editable datatables (DT) there is a different event call:
`input$<DT id>_cell_edit` as demontrated here:
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/pull/480

I was wondering, what other events can be observed other than values and **_cell_edit**? I can't find anything related with this but I would like to listen to cell click (not edit or double click, hover, focus, etc.).

I couldn't find anything in the reference or tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out by looking at the source files that there is also a "cell_clicked" event, which can be observed with `input$dt_cell_clicked`. Of course this doesn't completely answer the question.